# Show all record From table A with skipping matching record in Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select r.TableReservationId, d.TableId, d.TableName, d.StoreId
from dining_table d
  LEFT join dining_table_reservation r on d.TableId=r.TableId
where r.Status=0
  and r.StartTime not BETWEEN '2015-10-15 17:40:18' AND '2015-10-15 17:40:18'
```

This one showing only matching record but i want all record from dining_table and if record match with condition this record should be skip

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.TableReservationId, d.TableId, d.TableName, d.StoreId
from dining_table d
  LEFT join dining_table_reservation r on d.TableId=r.TableId
  AND r.Status=0
  and r.StartTime not BETWEEN '2015-10-15 17:40:18' AND '2015-10-15 17:40:18'
```

When `LEFT JOIN`, if put these right side table conditions in the `WHERE` clause it executes as a regular inner join. Move to `ON` clause instead!

Answer (score 0):

So you want all the records were there is no common values across the tables use `NOT IN` with your current results

```
SELECT * FROM dining_table where TableId NOT IN
(select r.TableReservationId, d.TableId, d.TableName, d.StoreId
from dining_table d
  LEFT join dining_table_reservation r on d.TableId=r.TableId
where r.Status=0
  and r.StartTime not BETWEEN '2015-10-15 17:40:18' AND '2015-10-15 17:40:18');
```

Comment: In B table Time is available then Table_Id of Table A skip from result